# How rotate each figure by 90 degrees?

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a coordinate system. I have a problem with the horizontal axis. I need to turn every number by 90 degrees.

my attempt:

```
  var canvasGraphElem = document.getElementById("canvasGraph");  
  canvasGraphElem.width = 300;
  canvasGraphElem.height = 200; 
  var ctx = canvasGraphElem.getContext('2d');

  for(var i = 0; i <= 300; i = i + 30) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = "10px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "right";
    ctx.translate(140, 140);
    ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2);
    ctx.fillText(i, 0 + i, 0 - 25);
    ctx.restore();
  };
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c84uugwq/1/)

The result should look like this:

[Image is teal with numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJXFO.png)

Comment: Once you transformed the canvas matrix, every drawing operations coordinates are also transformed. So if you rotate you context by 90deg, x axis becomes y axis and vice-versa. : https://jsfiddle.net/c84uugwq/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this two ways:

Rotating text using local transformation. This allows you to rotate the text independently an at any angle and it's easier to place text and "logic" locations, but it requires a few more steps.

Rotate the whole context at once. This require you to "switch" axis as x axis is now y, and vica verse. It also limit the rotation to 90° and you have to think in terms of switched axis.

## Method 1

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "10px sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline  = "middle";

for(var i = 0; i <= 300; i += 30) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 10 + i, 30);   // absolute transform
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI*0.25);                  // any angle (demo 45°)
  ctx.fillText(i, 0, 0);
};

ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);           // reset transforms
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

## Method 2

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "10px sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline  = "middle";
ctx.translate(20, 30);                        // set pivot
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI*0.5);                     // rotate canvas -90° around pivot

for(var i = 0; i <= 300; i += 30) {
  ctx.fillText(i, 10, i);                     // increase y, since now "y=x"
};

ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);           // reset transforms
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```