# How to rotate 180 text lables on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

Hey I have a canvas element which I am rotate 180 degree using the following code:

```
-moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
transform: scale(-1, 1);
filter: FlipH;
```

The canvas is get rotated but the text is flipped out.
Here is the the result:
[image]

I want to flip the text, after I have rotate the canvas 180 degree,apparently the text get rotate 180 too and I want to reverse it.
I want to rotate only the text and not all the other elements.

The original code is here:

go to **ticklines** function

http://codepen.io/Barak/pen/PNXROK

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, canvas.height);
    // https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4345236_A_Software_Implementation_of_the_Duval_Triangle_Method

    var v0 = {
      x: 50 * 10,
      y: (86.603 * 10)
    };
    var v1 = {
      x: 0 * 10,
      y: (0 * 10)
    };
    var v2 = {
      x: 100 * 10,
      y: (0 * 10)
    };
    var triangle = [v0, v1, v2];

    // Define all your segments here

    var segments = [{
      points: [{
        x: 0 * 10,
        y: 0 * 10
      }, {
        x: 43.5 * 10,
        y: 75.34461 * 10
      }, {
        x: 55 * 10,
        y: 55.42 * 10
      }, {
        x: 23 * 10,
        y: 0 * 10
      }],
      fill: 'rgb(172,236,222)',
      label: {
        text: '',
        cx: 300,
        cy: 645,
        withLine: false,
        endX: null,
        endY: null
      },
    }, {
      points: [{
        x: 23 * 10,
        y: 0 * 10
      }, {
        x: 55 * 10,
        y: 55.42 * 10
      }, {
        x: 63.5 * 10,
        y: 40.70 * 10
      }, {
        x: 55.5 * 10,
        y: 26.84 * 10
      }, {
        x: 71 * 10,
        y: 0 * 10
      }],
      fill: 'deepskyblue',
      label: {
        text: '',
        cx: 490,
        cy: 645,
        withLine: false,
        endX: null,
        endY: null
      },
    }, {
      points: [{
        x: 71 * 10,
        y: 0 * 10
      }, {
        x: 55.5 * 10,
        y: 26.84693 * 10
      }, {
        x: 63.5 * 10,
        y: 40.70341 * 10
      }, {
        x: 43.5 * 10,
        y: 75.34461 * 10
      }, {
        x: 48 * 10,
        y: 83.13888 * 10
      }, {
        x: 73 * 10,
        y: 39.83737 * 10
      }, {
        x: 67.5 * 10,
        y: 30.311 * 10
      }, {
        x: 85 * 10,
        y: 0 * 10
      }],
      fill: 'lightCyan',
      label: {
        text: '',
        cx: 656,
        cy: 645,
        withLine: false,
        endX: 366,
        endY: 120
      },
    }, { //here - I am in hell.-s5
      points: [{
        x: 49 * 10,
        y: 84.87093999999999 * 10
      }, {
        x: 50 * 10,
        y: 86.603 * 10
      }, {
        x: 51 * 10,
        y: 84.87093999999999 * 10
      }],
      fill: 'black',
      label: {
        text: 'PD',
        cx: 600,
        cy: 52,
        withLine: true,
        endX: 520,
        endY: 70
      },
    }, {
      points: [{
        x: 48 * 10,
        y: 83.1388 * 10
      }, {
        x: 49 * 10,
        y: 84.87093 * 10
      }, {
        x: 51 * 10,
        y: 84.87093 * 10
      }, {
        x: 60 * 10,
        y: 69.2824 * 10
      }, {
        x: 58 * 10,
        y: 65.81828 * 10
      }],
      fill: 'navajoWhite',
      label: {
        text: '',
        cx: 670,
        cy: 140,
        withLine: true,
        endX: 574,
        endY: 105
      },
    }, {
      points: [{
        x: 58 * 10,
        y: 65.81828 * 10
      }, {
        x: 60 * 10,
        y: 69.2824 * 10
      }, {
        x: 75 * 10,
        y: 43.3015 * 10
      }, {
        x: 73 * 10,
        y: 39.837 * 10
      }],
      fill: 'tan',
      label: {
        text: '',
        cx: 800,
        cy: 290,
        withLine: true,
        endX: 662,
        endY: 120
      },
    }, {
      points: [{
        x: 85 * 10,
        y: 0 * 10
      }, {
        x: 67.5 * 10,
        y: 30.311 * 10
      }, {
        x: 75 * 10,
        y: 43.3015 * 10
      }, {
        x: 100 * 10,
        y: 0
      }],
      fill: 'peru',
      label: {
        text: '',
        cx: 800,
        cy: 645,
        withLine: false,
        endX: null,
        endY: null
      },
    }, ];

    // label styles
    var labelfontsize = 12;
    var labelfontface = 'verdana';
    var labelpadding = 3;

    // pre-create a canvas-image of the arrowhead
    var arrowheadLength = 10;
    var arrowheadWidth = 8;
    var arrowhead = document.createElement('canvas');
    premakeArrowhead();

    var legendTexts = ['PD = Partial Discharge',
      'DT =  Discharges and Thermal',
      'T1 =  Thermal fault T < 300 ℃',
      'T2 =  Thermal fault 300 ℃ < T < 700 ℃',
      'T3 =  Thermal fault  T > 700 ℃',
      'D1 =  Discharges of low energy',
      'D2 =  Discharges of high energy'
    ];


    // start drawing
    /////////////////////


    // draw colored segments inside triangle
    for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
      drawSegment(segments[i]);
    }
    // draw ticklines
    //
    ticklines(v0, v1, 9, Math.PI * 1.2, 20);
    ticklines(v1, v2, 9, Math.PI * 3 / 4, 20);
    ticklines(v2, v0, 9, Math.PI * 2, 20);
    // molecules
    // moleculeLabel(v0, v1, 100, Math.PI / 2, '% CH4');
    // moleculeLabel(v1, v2, 100, 0, '% C2H4');
    //  moleculeLabel(v2, v0, 100, Math.PI, '% C2H2');
    // draw outer triangle
    drawTriangle(triangle);
    // draw legend
    //drawLegend(legendTexts, 10, 10, 12.86);
    drawCircle(canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 2, 2.5, 'red');

    // end drawing
    /////////////////////

    function drawCircle(point1, point2, radius, color) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(point1, point2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fill();
    }

    function drawSegment(s) {
      // draw and fill the segment path
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(s.points[0].x, s.points[0].y);
      for (var i = 1; i < s.points.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(s.points[i].x, s.points[i].y);
      }
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = s.fill;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.stroke();
      // draw segment's box label
      /*     if (s.label.withLine) {
            lineBoxedLabel(s, labelfontsize, labelfontface, labelpadding);
          } else {
            boxedLabel(s, labelfontsize, labelfontface, labelpadding);
          } */
    }


    function moleculeLabel(start, end, offsetLength, angle, text) {
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle'
      ctx.font = '14px verdana';
      var dx = end.x - start.x;
      var dy = end.y - start.y;
      var x0 = parseInt(start.x + dx * 0.50);
      var y0 = parseInt(start.y + dy * 0.50);
      var x1 = parseInt(x0 + offsetLength * Math.cos(angle));
      var y1 = parseInt(y0 + offsetLength * Math.sin(angle));
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.fillText(text, x1, y1);
      // arrow
      var x0 = parseInt(start.x + dx * 0.35);
      var y0 = parseInt(start.y + dy * 0.35);
      var x1 = parseInt(x0 + 50 * Math.cos(angle));
      var y1 = parseInt(y0 + 50 * Math.sin(angle));
      var x2 = parseInt(start.x + dx * 0.65);
      var y2 = parseInt(start.y + dy * 0.65);
      var x3 = parseInt(x2 + 50 * Math.cos(angle));
      var y3 = parseInt(y2 + 50 * Math.sin(angle));
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
      ctx.lineTo(x3, y3);
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.stroke();
      var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      ctx.save(); // save
      ctx.translate(x3, y3);
      ctx.rotate(angle);
      ctx.drawImage(arrowhead, -arrowheadLength, -arrowheadWidth / 2);
      ctx.restore()
    }


    function boxedLabel(s, fontsize, fontface, padding) {
      var centerX = s.label.cx;
      var centerY = s.label.cy;
      var text = s.label.text;
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle'
      ctx.font = fontsize + 'px ' + fontface
      var textwidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
      var textheight = fontsize * 1.286;
      var leftX = centerX - textwidth / 2 - padding;
      var topY = centerY - textheight / 2 - padding;
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.fillRect(leftX, topY, textwidth + padding * 2, textheight + padding * 2);
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.strokeRect(leftX, topY, textwidth + padding * 2, textheight + padding * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.fillText(text, centerX, centerY);
    }


    function lineBoxedLabel(s, fontsize, fontface, padding) {
      var centerX = s.label.cx;
      var centerY = s.label.cy;
      var text = s.label.text;
      var lineToX = s.label.endX;
      var lineToY = s.label.endY;
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle'
      ctx.font = fontsize + 'px ' + fontface
      var textwidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
      var textheight = fontsize * 1.286;
      var leftX = centerX - textwidth / 2 - padding;
      var topY = centerY - textheight / 2 - padding;
      // the line
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(leftX, topY + textheight / 2);
      ctx.lineTo(lineToX, topY + textheight / 2);
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.stroke();
      // the boxed text
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.fillRect(leftX, topY, textwidth + padding * 2, textheight + padding * 2);
      ctx.strokeRect(leftX, topY, textwidth + padding * 2, textheight + padding * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.fillText(text, centerX, centerY);
    }


    function ticklines(start, end, count, angle, length) {
      var dx = end.x - start.x;
      var dy = end.y - start.y;
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        var x0 = parseInt(start.x + dx * i / count);
        var y0 = parseInt(start.y + dy * i / count);
        var x1 = parseInt(x0 + length * Math.cos(180 - angle));
        var y1 = parseInt(y0 + length * Math.sin(180 - angle));
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
        ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
        ctx.stroke();
        if (i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8) {
          var labelOffset = length * 3 / 4;
          var x1 = parseInt(x0 - labelOffset * Math.cos(180 - angle));
          var y1 = parseInt(y0 - labelOffset * Math.sin(180 - angle));
          ctx.save();
          ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
          ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
          ctx.fillText(parseInt(i * 10), x1, y1);
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }
    }


    function premakeArrowhead() {
      var actx = arrowhead.getContext('2d');
      arrowhead.width = arrowheadLength;
      arrowhead.height = arrowheadWidth;
      actx.beginPath();
      actx.moveTo(0, 0);
      actx.lineTo(arrowheadLength, arrowheadWidth / 2);
      actx.lineTo(0, arrowheadWidth);
      actx.closePath();
      actx.fillStyle = 'black';
      actx.fill();
    }


    function drawTriangle(t) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(t[0].x, t[0].y);
      ctx.lineTo(t[1].x, t[1].y);
      ctx.lineTo(t[2].x, t[2].y);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.stroke();
    }


    function drawLegend(texts, x, y, lineheight) {
      ctx.textAlign = 'left';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.font = '12px arial';
      for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillText(texts[i], x, y + i * lineheight);
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
  padding: 10px;
}
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas" width=1024 height=1024></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167928/drawing-rotated-text-on-a-html5-canvas

Comment: I have tried this solution with no success,can you help me with the code himself and try it for yourself and see what it doesn't work properly?

Comment: did you try this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23523697/2907819

Comment: yes I have tried it,this is why I am posting my question. I have search google before post the question....

Comment: what happened when you tried it? post the code that didn't work

Comment: I have update the code.

Comment: Take a look at your [previous Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456577/how-to-create-duval-triangle-in-canvas) that already asks and answers this rotating text issue. In particular, look at the `ticklines` function that does exactly what you desire. Just curious, why aren't you using that code -- is there something I can explain in more detail? Cheers! :-)

Comment: This may help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245704/how-rotate-each-figure-by-90-degrees/36416250#36416250